# Is there a Node library that is a common interface between Mongo and SQL

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there some sort of Node library that is a common interface between Mongo and SQL? Something that I can use to write SQl and get data from mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) provides a unified interface over different SQL and NoSQL databases:

> Waterline is a brand new kind of storage and retrieval engine.
>
> It provides a uniform API for accessing stuff from different kinds of
>   databases, protocols, and 3rd party APIs. That means you write the
>   same code to get and store things like users, whether they live in
>   Redis, MySQL, MongoDB, or Postgres.